# PB formula to compare an ID field to a text field?

Tags: process-builder, formula, relationships, automation

I have a Relationship Process Builder that populates a Contact text field based on Status=Current and clears the field if someone changes the Status=Former. So far so good. Now how to get the Relationship PB to also verify the value in the Contact field? I think it's some variation on this, but if RelatedContact is a lookup (ie the ID) of that Important Contact name, how do I tweak this to match it to the text in the next field?

```
  ([Relationship__c].RelatedContact__c =
   [Relationship__c].Contact__r.ImportantContact__c)
```

Here is the entire formula in case it's useful:

```
AND (  
  ISPICKVAL([Relationship__c].Type__c , "Staff Contact"),  
  ISCHANGED([Relationship__c].Status__c ),  
  ISPICKVAL([Relationship__c].Status__c, "Former"),  
  ([Relationship__c].RelatedContact__c =  [Relationship__c].Contact__r.ImportantContact__c )  
 )
```

--
While troubleshooting, I tried this...

```
(TEXT([Relationship__c].RelatedContact__c) =
   [Relationship__c].Contact__r.ImportantContact__c)
```

...and got this

> The formula expression is invalid: Incorrect parameter type for function 'TEXT()'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, Picklist, received Text.

Comment: The error message is informing you that `RelatedContact__c` is already of the type Text and the `TEXT()` formula doesn't allow that as the parameter type. (i.e. converting text to text).

Comment: Thanks, do you have any recommendations for how to get this criteria to work? I need to make sure [Relationship__c].RelatedContact__c equals [Relationship__c].Contact__r.ImportantContact__c